# Magento 2 admin form not loading

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, forms, uicomponent

I am trying to create admin form using ui_component in magento 2 but form is not display in admin here is code that i tried.

view/adminhtml/layout/hello_world_edit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="hello_world_edit"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

view/adminhtml/ui_component/hello_world_edit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">test_form.test_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">test_form.test_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Test Information</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">test_form</item>
        </item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="test_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Excellence\Hello\Model\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">test_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="test_details">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Test Details</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="title">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Title</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">test</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">title</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Model/DataProvider.php

```
<?php
namespace Excellence\Hello\Model;

use Excellence\Hello\Model\ResourceModel\Test\CollectionFactory;

class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{
    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $primaryFieldName
     * @param string $requestFieldName
     * @param CollectionFactory $testCollectionFactory
     * @param array $meta
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        CollectionFactory $testCollectionFactory,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->collection = $testCollectionFactory->create();
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Get data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">


    <virtualType name="Excellence\Hello\Model\Resource\Test\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">excellence_hello_test</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Excellence\Hello\Model\ResourceModel\Test</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="test_form_data_source" xsi:type="string">Excellence\Hello\Model\Resource\Test\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

</config>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

here sum mistake in your ui component  **hello_world_edit.xml**

```
<item name="provider" xsi:type="string">test_form.test_form_data_source</item>
<item name="deps" xsi:type="string">test_form.test_form_data_source</item>
```

Change above lines as per below

```
<item name="provider" si:type="string">hello_world_edit.test_form_data_source</item>
<item name="deps" xsi:type="string">hello_world_edit.test_form_data_source</item>
```

**Or try this**

view/adminhtml/ui_component/hello_world_edit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">hello_world_edit.test_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">hello_world_edit.test_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Test Information</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">hello_world_edit</item>
        </item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="test_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Excellence\Hello\Model\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">test_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="test_details">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Test Details</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="title">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Title</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">test</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">title</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```